# register type variable value is not updating

Tags: verilog

Problem statement

Consider a parking lot with a single entry and exit gate. Two pairs of photo sensors (a,b) are used to monitor the activity of cars.
When an object is between the photo transmitter and the photo receiver, the light is blocked and the corresponding output is asserted to 1. By monitoring the events of two sensors, we can determine whether a car is entering or exiting or a pedestrian is passing through. For example, the following sequence indicates that a car enters the lot:

> Initially, both sensors are unblocked (i.e., the a and b signals are "00").
>   Sensor a is blocked (i.e., the a and b signals are " 10").
>   Both sensors are blocked (i.e., the a and b signals are "1 1 ").
>   Sensor a is unblocked (i.e., the a and b signals are "01 ").
>   Both sensors becomes unblocked (i.e., the a and b signals are "00").

Design a parking lot occupancy counter as follows:

1. Design an FSM with two input signals, a and b, and two output signals, `enter` and `exit` . The `enter` and `exit` signals assert one clock cycle when a car enters and one clock cycle when a car exits the lot, respectively.
2. Derive the HDL code for the FSM.

The following code is used:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module assignment1(a,b,clk,reset,en,ex);
input a,b,clk,reset;
output en,ex;
reg en,ex;
reg [1:0] state,next_state;
parameter unBlocked=2'b00,aBlocked=2'b10,bothBlocked=2'b11,bBlocked=2'b01;
// State register block
//if(reset)
//state<=unBlocked;
//else
always@(posedge clk) begin
state<=next_state;
end
//
always @(state or a or b) begin

case (state)

unBlocked:  if((a==1'b1) && (b==1'b0))

begin  next_state=aBlocked; en=0; end

else next_state=unBlocked;

aBlocked:if((a==1'b1) && (b==1'b1))

 begin next_state=bothBlocked; en=0; end

else next_state=unBlocked;

bothBlocked: if((a==1'b0) && (b==1'b1))

begin next_state=bBlocked; en=0; end

else next_state=unBlocked;

bBlocked: if((a==1'b0) && (b==1'b0))

  begin next_state=unBlocked; en=1; end  

  else next_state=unBlocked;

  endcase
  end
endmodule
```

I am trying to create a moore machine when car enters.  In next_state variable I am only getting 00 i.e unBlocked state...That is states are not updating according to the inputs.Here inputs are a,b...car enters into the parking only when(a,b) take values 00,10,11,01,00.can you please help in this?

Comment: did you know that two spaces at the end of the line will prevent the block of text running on? Try that with your problem statement to make it easier to read.

Comment: @bibo Please ask a specific question when posting, your problem statement looks great. Now a question for the readers to answer would also be great

Comment: Please also properly indent your code, and formulate your if/else as: `if (...) begin`/`end else begin`/`end`. While `begin`/`end` are not always required, your code will be a lot easier to follow and understand if you don't omit them.

Comment: I am new here...This is my first post. I am trying to create a moore machine when car enters.  In next_state variable I am not only getting 00 i.e unBlocked state...That is states are not changing....can you please help in this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the reset is not being used. This means your state is not being intialized, which means it is an 'x' or unknown value at the beginning of the simulation. This then causes the case statement to not match anything and this leads to no response to the inputs.

On general you should be vigilant about the basics like always resetting registers and also checking for any x's in simulation after reset is released. It will save you loads of time down the road